# Error inside trigger. PLS-00201: identifier 'mySchema.Myfunction' must be declared. Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote trigger on oracle. I have error when i try to invoke function inside trigger:  error PLS-00201: identifier 'mySchema.Myfunction' must be declared. Can somoeone show me how should i declare it? Thanks.

```
create or replace 
trigger myTrigger
 BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF name_of_A ON schema_A.myTable
 FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  A                   varchar2(10);
BEGIN
  A := :new.name_of_A;
  IF A IS NOT NULL THEN
    :new.name_of_A := schema_B.Myfunction( A);
  END IF;
END;
```

---

Solution:

Added script on schema_a:

```
grant execute on myfunction to schema_a;
```

Also changed

```
:new.name_of_A := schema_B.Myfunction( A);
```

Into:

```
:new.name_of_A := MYFUNCTION( A);
```

And it works. Thanks for help!

Comment: Has SCHEMA_B granted execute on `myfunction` to you?

Comment: Im not sure how to check it. myFuntion is function from my second schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect as schema_b

```
SQL> conn schema_b/password
```

Then grant the necessary privilege:

```
SQL> grant execute on myfunction to schema_a;
```

Now schema_a should be able to compile its triggers.

Comment: unfortunately didn't help. Plus i will share this trigger with other people so Im not sure if its good solution to fix this .

Comment: Which user owns trigger?